# Como centralizar um TextView?

Tags: android, xml

Como centralizar o texto horizontal no `TextView` ou seja centralizar na linha de cima e de baixo.

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Texto"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Texto"/>
```

Dessa forma, vai centralizar horizontalmente e verticalmente. Se precisar apenas horizontalmente:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Texto"/>
```

Ou programaticamente:

```
seuTexview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Mais detalhes você pode ver aqui na **[documentação do android](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:gravity)**.

Comment: Valeu deu certo

Comment: @Rodolfo que bom que resolveu. Lembre-se de marcar como aceita, para servir de referência para outras pessoas com dúvida parecida. :D

Comment: e se eu quiser centralizar  com center e depois e também deixar ele no lado direito? ou seja centralizado e a direita

Answer (score 1):

Para setar na hora de popular o campo:
`campo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`

Para voltar ao estado inicial
`campo.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);`

Para setar a esquerda:
`campo.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);`

Para setar a direita:
`campo.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);`

Comment: Mas não tem como fazer isso direto no XML!? Assim já iniciaria como ele quer!

Comment: Sim, pode ser feito no XML como o Articuno respondeu anteriormente. dentro da tag da TextView adicione android:gravity="center_horizontal" ou outra posição que precise

Comment: Opa. Sua resposta apareceu na revisão, então não dava para ver a resposta do Articuno. Tranquilo companheiro! ;)